# MPAndroidChart barchart y axis label colors

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to set different label color for y-axis label in **mpandroidchart** ? is possible how? any help appreciated.

Comment: I want to set LABEL colors,I want different label color for each labels. ex:- 0 - red ,1- blue etc

Answer (score 7):

Add below code of line

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red)); // left y-axis
```

[image]

Comment: I want different label color for each labels. ex:- 0 - red ,1- blue etc

Comment: you are using Mpchart dependency or library?

Comment: I added dependency in gradle.

Comment: As far my knowledge, there is no way to set different colors of left side values because they provided single method which is setTextColor.

Also if you check there libarary, their all charts have single colored values at left side. 
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: unfortunately looks like!

Answer (score 1):

You can custom YAxisRenderer like this to achieve it.
Add it to your chart

  `chart.setRendererLeftYAxis(new MyYAxisLeftRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(),
         chart.getAxisLeft(),chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)));`

```
public class MyYAxisLeftRenderer extends YAxisRenderer {


@Override
protected void drawYLabels(Canvas c, float fixedPosition, float[] positions, float offset) {
    final int from = mYAxis.isDrawBottomYLabelEntryEnabled() ? 0 : 1;
    final int to = mYAxis.isDrawTopYLabelEntryEnabled()
            ? mYAxis.mEntryCount
            : (mYAxis.mEntryCount - 1);

    // draw
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {

        String text = mYAxis.getFormattedLabel(i);

        // change y label color here before drawing (i is an index of label)
         mAxisLabelPaint.setColor();

        c.drawText(text, fixedPosition, positions[i * 2 + 1] + offset, mAxisLabelPaint);
    }
}
```